# NullReferenceException when using TestContext in NUnit 2.5.8

Tags: c#, nunit

Recently upgraded to NUnit 2.5.8 in order to use the new TestContext functionality. This is so that we can determine the current test name in order to retrieve an attribute:

```
private T GetAttribute<T>() where T : class
{
  return Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(GetType().GetMethod(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name), typeof(T)) as T;
}
```

However, we are seeing NullReferenceExceptions when accessing the property TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name because it seems that the NUnit CallContext is not being registered properly.

Has anyone else encountered this problem, or can suggest an alternative way of determining the current test name from the SetUp?

Comment: How are you running the test? Are you using a specific test runner that might be the problem?

Comment: It's being exhibited by the NUnit GUI runner and the Resharper runner.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to your question, but I came across a similar issue when using [TestDriven.NET's xcopy-deployable NUnit Test Runner](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2009/11/05/testdriven-net-2-24-xcopy-deployable-test-runners.aspx) to use NUnit 2.5.7, and hitting a `NullReferenceException` because TestDriven.NET was still running the tests under 2.5.5 (which it ships with) and not the NUnit my project referenced.

The problem turned out to be that I was referencing the `nunit.framework.dll` found in `NUnit\NUnit-2.5.7.10213\bin\net-2.0` when I needed to be referencing the one found in `NUnit\NUnit-2.5.7.10213\bin\net-2.0\framework`. Why there are two copies I have no idea, but pointing to the right DLL made all the difference.